# Django Forms - Relating Objects (Model Formsets?)

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Say I have something like this:

```
class Product(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    description models.TextField()

class Image(models.Model)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True, related_name="images")
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Suppose I'm in a form for creating a `Product` and in this form there is a section that allows you to upload images. These images are uploaded asynchronously. How can I have it so that:

On creation:
   Product is created and images are related to it.

On editing:
   Product is fetched, related Images are fetched. Product is edited, Images are edited.

Currently, I have a view that does both jobs of creating or editing `Products`. How can I accomplish the image related part of this product form? Model Formsets?

**Edit:**

```
@login_required
def create_or_edit_product(request, product_id=None):
    # Redirect user if he has no account associated to him
    try:
        account = Account.objects.get(membership__user=request.user)
    except:
        login_url = reverse('login') + ('?next=%s') % request.path
        return HttpResponseRedirect(login_url)

    # Get product if product id passed
    product_instance = None
    if product_id is not None:
        product_instance = get_object_or_404(product, id=product_id)

    # Get related pictures if product exists. Get picture values (dictionary list, used for initial formset data) if pictures found.
    pictures = product.pictures.all() if product_instance is not None else None
    pictures_values = pictures.values() if pictures else []

    PictureFormSet = formset_factory(PictureForm, formset=BasePictureFormSet, extra=0, can_delete=False, max_num=40)

    if request.method == "POST":
        product_form = productForm(request.POST, prefix='product', instance=product_instance)
        picture_formset = PictureFormSet(request.POST, prefix='pictures', initial=pictures_values)

        # If forms are valid
        if product_form.is_valid() and picture_formset.is_valid():
            try:
                # Add account to product and save
                product = product_form.save(commit=False)
                if product_instance is None:
                    product.account = account
                product.save()

                # Remove picture-product relationships of current pictures
                if pictures is not None:
                    pictures.update(product=None)

                # Update each picture with the product and corresponding sort order. (The field 'id' is a picture object. The form converts the passed picture id to a picture object)
                for index, form in enumerate(picture_formset):
                    picture = form.cleaned_data['id']
                    Picture.objects.filter(id=picture.id).update(product=product, sort_order=index)

            except Exception, e:
                # Rollback changes - something went wrong
                transaction.rollback()
                print "Transaction Rollback: %s" % e
            else:
                # Commit changes and redirect to product edit page
                transaction.commit()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('product_edit', product_id=product.id)
    else:
        product_form = productForm(prefix='product', instance=product_instance)
        picture_formset = PictureFormSet(prefix='pictures')

    # TODO: change add template to an add/edit one
    return render_to_response('products/add.html', {
        'product_form' : product_form,
        'picture_formset' : picture_formset,
        'pictures' : pictures,
    }, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm new to Python and Django but that is my somewhat working view. (I've only tried adding a new product so far)

The form that the user sees has thumbnails with hidden inputs containing each picture id. In the case that the form fails, I'd like to re display thumbnails along with the hidden inputs (which are already kept). To make that work, I'm guessing I'd have to query the picture ids, but the form is not valid so how would I go about doing that? (if that is even the right path to go about)

What do you think?

Comment: Yes [Model Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

Answer (score 0):

@Aamir Adnan is right that `Model Formsets` are an elegant way to deal with this.

Here's a full fledge example that is similar to what you need - http://stellarchariot.com/blog/2011/02/dynamically-add-form-to-formset-using-javascript-and-django/

As in the example, because the end user may need to add additional "images" (in your case) which are related to the product, you will need some javascript logic to handle the dynamic addition of forms so that the user can arbitrarily add and upload images on save.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you possible include some sample code?  I'm trying to get it to work but I'm having no luck. I currently save the product, save the formset with a `commit=False`, loop through assigning/saving images to products -- but it does not work. It gives me an `IndexError: list index out of range`. Also, what exactly is the queryset supposed to be? none()? All images? All images belonging to product? I'm quite lost.

Comment: Can you add in your view function showing how you do a `commit=False` and image assignments?

Comment: There's a very good example here (without using javascript) that you can refer to but note that you will need to use `multipart` form in your html because you are uploading images. reference http://www.brantsteen.com/blog/django-adding-inline-formset-rows-without-javascript/

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- After trying to use model formsets I've apparently got normal formsets to work. There is just one problem that I haven't worked out and I was wondering if you could give me your opinion. I'm looking to be able to re display images on form validation failure. The image ids (which are passed as hidden form fields) are kept, but I'd like to be able to query those so I can re display in the template. Not sure I am making sense, please let me know. Thank you for your assistance - its been quite helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to clean up the code -- I'll try to edit/include it in my original post as soon as possible.